# Linked Frameworks & Libraries vs. Link Binary with Libraries

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

What's the difference between Linked Frameworks and Libraries and Link Binary with libraries of Xcode's General and Build Phases tab. Screenshots attached.

[image: Build Phases]

[image: General]

Comment: I think the General tab is just a shortcut/link to other things that get used a lot, and usually made "easier" in that tab. Now, if Apple would just let us scroll left and right, I could use these screens a bit easier without closing the panels or buying giant monitors just to use an option pane

Comment: ^^^This should be the answer ^^^
Also the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html) says:
`Alternative: Select the target in the project editor and click General. Click the Add button (+) in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section, choose a framework, and click Add.`